# How to search the ManagedEntity by regular expression in ViJava

Tags: java, sdk, vmware, vsphere

I'm using ViJava 5.5-beta.
For example I want to find all VMs which names contains "SQL".
To search I get all ManagedEntities of "VirtalMachine" type and iterate them.
Can you tell me, is there any fast search method to do that?

```
serviceInstance = new ServiceInstance(new URL(vCenter), Constants.USERNAME, Constants.PASSWORD, true);
            Folder rootFolder = serviceInstance.getRootFolder();
            ManagedEntity[] mes = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");
            for (ManagedEntity me : mes) {
// ....if (name.contains("SQL"))......
}
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it, I'm afraid. There is no way to pass on the filtering to the server. We do something similar but don't use the String.contains() method and instead use Java's pattern matcher. One optimization that we do is to compile the pattern we want to match before hand (out of the for loop). That way we, probably, save a few milliseconds in each loop

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is going to be the best way to do it. There is no way to pass a filter in to the server so that filtering happens server side, and the method you are using does a property collector and only gets the "name" property so it is the most efficient.

Just a suggestion: [yavijava](http://www.yavijava.com/) is an open source drop in replacement for vijava with full support for vSphere 6.0 We have an active community and many enhanced features that vijava is lacking.

Comment: I second the yavijava plug. We use it for our product and I think that's the way forward. The open source version of vijava (vijava.sourceforge.net) seems pretty much dead and Steve, the author, has moved on to other things.